# Applying animations in MVVM? (old method was done dynamically in code-behind)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding, mvvm, windows-phone

I'm trying hard to adopt the MVVM design pattern but running into a few roadblocks, one of which is the following:

I have a **Listbox** populated by bound **Monster** objects, each of which contain a **ProgressBar** denoting the Monster's hit points.

I then have an "attack" **Button** outside of the Listbox that causes the selected Monster to take damage whenever it is clicked. (SelectedMonster is a property in my ViewModel that is TwoWay-Bound to the SelectedItem property of the ListBox).

All of this works great. When the button is clicked, the selected Monster takes damage on the ProgressBar is updated accordingly.

The problem is, what I want to do is apply an animation on the ProgressBar as it changes.

Before, when I had an "attack" button in each row of the ListBox, I was setting the animation dynamically in code and it worked quite well (using a helper method FindDescendent I found online):

**Page.xaml**

```
<Storyboard x:Name="MonsterHPStoryboard">
    <DoubleAnimation x:Name="MonsterHPAnimation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value" />
</Storyboard>
```

**Page.xaml.cs**

```
private void AttackMonsterButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Monster Monster = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Monster;

    ProgressBar HPBar = FindDescendant<ProgressBar>(((sender as Button).Parent as Grid).Parent as Grid);

    Storyboard.SetTarget(MonsterHPAnimation, HPBar);

    // set the From value to the Monster's current HP
    MonsterHPAnimation.SetValue(DoubleAnimation.FromProperty, (Double)Monster.HP);

    // set the To value to the Monster's HP after being attacked - returned by ThePlayer.Attack()
    MonsterHPAnimation.SetValue(DoubleAnimation.ToProperty, (Double)ThePlayer.Attack(Monster, Battle));

    // set the duration of the animation to 250 ms
    MonsterHPAnimation.SetValue(DoubleAnimation.DurationProperty, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)));

    MonsterHPStoryboard.Begin();
}
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this going the MVVM route? Is there an easier way to tell the animation to play any time the value of the ProgressBar changes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use an interaction trigger with an animation action. You should be able to do it all in declarative XAML. The trigger will be a property in the VM that implements INPC. Then you'll use a worker thread and use the progress event to update property that is bound to the interaction trigger.

Comment: thanks! did you mean event trigger? Also I'm not seeing 'animation action' in Blend... I wonder if it's because I'm running the VS2010 version (apparently the 'Expression' line is discontinued)